# Take picam image while motion is running

Tags: video, camera, motion

I am running motion on my raspberry pi using the V4L2 driver. While motion is running, I can't take a snapshot using raspistill. Is is possible to take a snapshot of the virtual V4L2 device using another tool while motion is running?

I guess /dev/video0 (created by V4L2) should be accessible by multiple clients? But which tool would I use to take a snapshot?

Comment: Do you get any output from `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-formats`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should look to [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) in order to allow to open "twice" a V4L2 device.

1 - It will allow to create a virtual video device using :

> ```
> sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms    
> sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=10
> ```

This will add a new device /dev/video10

2 - Next you will need to copy the real device (/dev/video0) to the virtual one (/dev/video10) using ffmpeg or gstreamer.

- using ffmpeg

> ```
> sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
> ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video10
> ```

- using gstreamer

> ```
> sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
> gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video10
> ```

- using [v4l2tools](https://github.com/mpromonet/v4l2tools) (some of my tries with V4L2 programming)

> ```
> git clone https://github.com/mpromonet/v4l2tools
> sudo apt-get install liblog4cpp5-dev
> make v4l2copy
> ./v4l2copy /dev/video0 /dev/video10
> ```

3 - Finally the v4l2loopback virtual device, that could be openned severals times,
could be used by motion and an other one to take snasphot (for instance using webcam or [v4l2grab](http://www.twam.info/linux/v4l2grab-grabbing-jpegs-from-v4l2-devices))

Comment: thanks to everyone here. I broke my installation so I couldn't test it yet, but this sounds very well - let's hope the resource consumption won't be too high.