# Raspbian v4l2loopback

Tags: raspbian, v4l2

I'm trying to load v4l2 modules. Before doing that, I run:

```
sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms
```

but, when I load the module, I get an error:

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=4
modprobe: FATAL: Module v4l2loopback not found.
```

My OS:

```
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.17+ #838 Tue Feb 9 12:57:10 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

I've followed every step of the question *[Take picam image while motion is running](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19630/take-picam-image-while-motion-is-running)*, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to install v4l2loopback on a Raspberry Pi 4

I was able to fix it by installing the Raspberry Pi Kernal Headers

`sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers`

My system via `uname -a`

`Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback

```
    git clone https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback.git
    cd v4l2loopback
    make && sudo make install
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice to see...